# Transforming JavaPairDStream into RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using Spark streaming with Spark MLlib to evaluate a naive bayes model. Actually, I reach to point where I can't go ahead since I could not transform the object of JavaPairDStream into RDD to calculate the accuracy. The result of prediction and labels are stored in this JavaPairDStream but I want to go through each one of them and compare to calculate the accuracy.

I will post my code to make my question more clear, The code raise an exception in the part of calculating the accuracy (The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) JavaDStream, double) (because this way is only working with JavaPairRDD not), I need a help to calculate the accuracy for JavaPairDStream.

Edit: I edited the code, my problem now is how to read the value of accuracy which is JavaDStream and then accumulate this value for each batch of data to calculate the accuracy for all data.

```
public static JSONArray testSparkStreaming(){

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My app").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.milliseconds(500));

    String savePath = "path to saved model";
    final NaiveBayesModel savedModel = NaiveBayesModel.load(jssc.sparkContext().sc(), savePath);

    JavaDStream<String> data = jssc.textFileStream("path to CSV file");
    JavaDStream<LabeledPoint> testData = data.map(new Function<String, LabeledPoint>() {
        public LabeledPoint call(String line) throws Exception {
            List<String> featureList = Arrays.asList(line.trim().split(","));
            double[] points = new double[featureList.size()-1];
            double classLabel = Double.parseDouble(featureList.get(featureList.size() - 1));
            for (int i = 0; i < featureList.size()-1; i++){
                points[i] = Double.parseDouble(featureList.get(i));
            }

            return new LabeledPoint(classLabel, Vectors.dense(points));
        }
    });


  JavaPairDStream<Double, Double> predictionAndLabel = testData.mapToPair(new  PairFunction<LabeledPoint, Double, Double>() {
        public Tuple2<Double, Double> call(LabeledPoint p) {
            return new Tuple2<Double, Double>(savedModel.predict(p.features()), p.label());
        }
    });


    JavaDStream<Long> accuracy = predictionAndLabel.filter(new Function<Tuple2<Double, Double>, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(Tuple2<Double, Double> pl) throws JSONException {

            return pl._1().equals(pl._2());
        }
    }).count();

    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
    System.out.println("*************");

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


    jsonArray.put(obj);
    obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("Accuracy", accuracy*100 + "%");
    jsonArray.put(obj);

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: the method "transform" ina DStream allows you to apply a function over every RDD in a DStream

Comment: @ rhernando, I updated the code, do you have any idea about how can I read the value of accuracy which is JavaDStream and then accumulate this value for each batch of data to calculate the accuracy for all data.

Comment: If you want to accumulate the result, just use the accumulator:  Accumulator<Integer> accum = sc.accumulator(0); Instead of count, do "filter...foreach(accum.add(1))". BTW: you should put jssc.start at the end of the program

Comment: Yes, I want to accumulate the results in order to calculate the accuracy of the model, but if I understand you correctly, do you mean using accumulator on predictionAndLabel which is JavaPairDStream<Double, Double>???, I have two more questions please, the first one: how can I stop the jssc after streaming all the records which were exist in the file when I started jssc? The second question: Is streaming works properly with csv file or I have to convert it to hdfs or any other format??--- Thanks

Comment: If you are processing just one file, why are you using streaming? I think a batch processing (with sc.textFile) would be more suitable

Comment: Actually, I'm comparing between the results in terms of running the code in batch mode and streaming mode. My code in batch mode is working properly but I have some troubles in streaming mode as you see and I could not solve it until now.